# Соединить списки

Tags: c#, linq

Есть коллекция объектов A в каждом из объектов A есть коллекция объектов B и есть просто объект B. Как с помощью LINQ получить коллекцию объектов B соединив объект B c всеми коллекциями объектов B в коллекции объектов A?

Comment: А можно пример такой коллекции и той, которую хотите в итоге получить?

Comment: А какую практическую задачу решаем, пытаясь соединить коллекции разных типов? Вы хотите их проитерировать за один раз, у них обоих реализован интерфейс/наследуются от базового класса?

Comment: @AK "пытаясь соединить коллекции разных типов" — но автор сообщения не пытается соединить разные типы- он хочет получить коллекцию которая состоит из объекта B + все остальные объекты B, которые находятся в коллекциях у объектов А.

Comment: Вам нужны дублирующиеся записи в результирующей коллекции?

Comment: @Anamnian Кстати да, это более точное прочтение. Не люблю вопросы в которых слишком много двусмысленностей.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, есть типы

```
class B
{
}

class A
{
    public List<B> BCollection = new List<B>();
}
```

Инициализируем их

```
var aCollection = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new A() {BCollection = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(y=>new B()).ToList()});
var b = new B();
```

Объеденим все B типы

```
var unionOfB = aCollection.SelectMany(x => x.BCollection).Concat(new[] {b});
```

Если у вас .NET 4.7.1+, вместо `Concat` несколько эффективнее будет использовать [`Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt823360(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var unionOfB = aCollection.SelectMany(x => x.BCollection).Append(b);
```

Comment: Если у нас .NET 4.7.1+, вместо `Concat` несколько эффективнее будет использовать [`Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/mt823360(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @АндрейNOP слишком новая версия для меня, но спасибо за инфу, добавил в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Пример если типы одинаковые :

```
        var B = new T();
        var ListB = new List<T>();
        var listA = new List<T>();

        listA = listA.Concat(ListB).Append(B).ToList();
```

Пример если объекты имеют разные типы, но `B` наследуется от `A`:

```
    private class A {}
    private class B : A  { } 

    private void Test()
    {
        var B = new B();
        var ListB = new List<B>();
        var listA = new List<A>();

        listA = listA.Concat(ListB).Append(B).ToList();
    }
```

Пример если типы разные, нет наследования и реализации одного интерфейса то просто в лист `object` :

```
    var B = new B();
    var ListB = new List<B>();
    var listA = new List<A>();

    var test = listA.Select(x => x as object).Concat(ListB.Select(x => x as object)).Append(B as object)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: У топикстартера коллекции имеют разные типы, а у вас одинаковые: вы решали другую задачу.

Comment: @AK добавил решение где типы разные

Comment: вместо `.Select(x => x as object)` можно юзать `.OfType<object>()` или `.Cast<object>()`